# Error al devolver datos JSon del controlador

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tengo el siguiente código en mi controller donde envío el listado de ciudades a un *jsonResult*

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
 //la linea anterior es donde instancio el modelo de datos o data context
    public JsonResult GetDataCiudades()
    {
        var CiudadesJson =  db.ciudad.ToListAsync(); // from model 

        return Json(CiudadesJson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Y cuando intento devolver este JsonResult de la vista uso el siguiente código ...

```
else {
            $('#Ciudad').find('option').remove();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetDataCiudades", "GenerarCertificado")',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                data: "{}",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                   var result = JSON.parse(data);
                    $.each(result, function (index, value) {
                        var option = $('<option value="' + index + '">' + value + '</option>');
                        $('#Ciudad').append(option);
                    });
                },
                error: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                    alert('Error al cargar Ciudades.');
                }
            });
        }
```

Pero me devuelve un montón de objetos y caracteres en la Lista desplegable que estoy mostrando en la vista...

[image: errorjson]

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Hola ger, **¿que recibes exactamente en `data` del `success`?**, porque al parecer tienes algo como esto `{dato1:{objeto:{objeto1:"info",objeto2:"info",objeto3:"info",}},dato2:"informacion",dato3:"informacion"}`

Comment: si @JuankGlezz exactamente es lo que recibe el data success!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He tenido el mismo problema, y lo que me ha funcionado es cambiar el método:

```
public string GetDataCiudades()
{
    var CiudadesJson =  db.ciudad.ToListAsync(); // from model 

    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CiudadesJson);
}
```

Confío más en el resultado de la libería [Newtonsoft.Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) que en la nativa de C#, pero eso es solo en mi experiencia. Ojalá esto ayude a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Basándome en en este `Json`

```
{ dato1:
  { objeto:
    { 
      objeto1:"info",
      objeto2:"info",
      objeto3:"info"‌​
    }
  },
  dato2:"informaci‌​on",
  dato3:"informaci‌​on"
}
```

Lo que puedes hacer es recorrer el `Json` interno `objeto: { ... }`

```
success: function (data) {
  var result = JSON.parse(data);
  //este ciclo solo si necesitas los valores del objeto interno
  //este .each recorrerá únicamente el objeto interno
  $.each(result.objeto, function (index, value) {
    var option = $('<option value="' + index + '">' + value + '</option>');
    $('#Ciudad').append(option);
  });


  //suponiendo que necesitas todos los valores del Json
  $.each(result, function (index, value) {
    if(value.objeto != undefined){//validando que el value tenga un objeto
      //recorriendo el objeto interno
      $.each(value.objeto, function (index1, value1) {
        var option = $('<option value="' + index1 + '">' + value1 + '</option>');
        $('#Ciudad').append(option);
      });
    }
    var option = $('<option value="' + index + '">' + value + '</option>');
    $('#Ciudad').append(option);
  });
},
```

En caso de que lance error con `result.objeto` prueba con `result[0].objeto`

Comment: nooo el json debe arrojar nombre de ciudades como mexico quito, bogota caracas... pero en vez de eso me arroja object asi como lo que muestra el primer post la image

Comment: el `json` que use solo fue para basarme en lo que tu recibías obviamente la información cambia al igual que las variables del objeto, pero intentaste con lo que te he colocado como respuesta?